# Scroll to an element that has position sticky

Tags: javascript, css, angular

So I have an element that resides at the bottom of my list using:

```
position: sticky;
bottom: 0;
```

And I am using `scrollIntoView(true)` to scroll to it. There is two problems though.

1. It scrolls first to a position where the sticky element in in its original position. Not stickied to the bottom. Then you have to fire the `scrollIntoView` once again so it scrolls the element to the top.
2. ScrollIntoView scrolls the whole window too even though the element is inside a scrollable container.

I can't find a solution for either problem. My goal is to have a sticky element and be able to align it to the top when clicking it. I am using Angular but I don't really think that matters.

Comment: Not to spam with you with just a link, but this person has a very good post on most everything about position sticky and scrolling which may help you with your alignment issue:  https://mastery.games/post/position-sticky/

Comment: @EspressoBeans Hey, it's a great article but sadly it doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
  scrollTo(container: HTMLUListElement, header: HTMLLIElement) {
    container.scrollTo(0, header.offsetTop);
    container.scrollTo(0, header.offsetTop);
  }
```

It's important that you neither use smooth scrolling in the scrollTo function or `scroll-behavior: "smooth"` in CSS.

And don't forget to add `position: relative` to the container.

Comment: Did you mean `container.scrollTo(0, 0);` on the first line? if so - it works, but will break once you want the have smooth scrolling